# How can I create a typed Tuple2 from Java / Spring?

Tags: java, scala, spring, tuples

I want to be able to create a `Tuple2` from spring config where I explicitly declare the types of my parameters:

```
<bean class="scala.Tuple2">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="Europe/London" type="java.util.TimeZone" />
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="America/New_York" type="java.util.TimeZone" />
</bean>
```

This does not work (I have the relevant property editors specified in my config file). At runtime I get the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scala.Tuple2#6504bc' defined in file [C:\Work\myproj\config\test\myproj.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Object]:
>   **Ambiguous constructor argument types** - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

The error goes away if I do not declare the explicit `type` - but then of course the `Tuple2` in my program is just a `(String, String)` which is not what I want.

---

**EDIT for those of you who did not know this**, Spring uses `PropertyEditor`s to create instances from Strings as follows:

```
public class TimeZoneEditor extends java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport {
    public void setAsText(String text) { setValue(TimeZone.getTimeZone(text)); }
    public String getAsText() { return ((TimeZone)getValue()).getID(); }
}
```

Now I simply declare in my config:

```
<bean id="customEditorConfigurer" 
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">   
    <property name="customEditors"> 
        <map>
            <entry key="java.util.TimeZone">
                <bean class="my.cleve.rutil.TimeZoneEditor"/> 
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

And hey presto I can do things like:

```
<map key-type="java.util.TimeZone" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
    <entry key="Europe/London" value="4" />
</map>
```

Or alternatively Spring can figure out the generic type parameters from your setter methods. Except it doesn't seem to work in the case of my `Tuple2`!

Comment: Did you try creating TimeZone beans separately and then referencing as arguments to the Tuple2 constructor?
Also, how is spring converting strings to TimeZones?

Comment: Jon - I've modified my question with how to do this

Comment: I wouldn't think there would be anything special about scala here.  Defining a generic class like "Pair<F,S>" in java should be equivalent to Tuple2.  Type erasure will make the constructor look like: public scala.Tuple2(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)

Comment: Jon - agreed. But when I try and use Java to do `new Tuple2()`, my IDE thinks the constructor has no parameters, so I'm not entirely sure what the Scala `Tuple2` *looks like* from a Java perspective

Comment: I would be very surprised if a java Pair<F,S> worked but Tuple2 does not.  They should look exactly the same from a java reflection perspective.  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Tuple2.class.getConstructors()));.
-- I apologize that if these comments are not helping solve the problem.  I'm not a spring user.

Comment: I'll try that Jon - looks like I need to play about some more. I've a workaround for now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the TimeZone parameters explicitly using the static method getTimeZone() of class TimeZone:

```
<bean class="scala.Tuple2">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <bean class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
      <constructor-arg value="Europe/London"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="1">
    <bean class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
      <constructor-arg value="America/New_York"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to do this, Walter. For example I can create a `Map` whose value-types are `TimeZone`s in the way I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

It may be working for Map because spring has special support for it through the syntax you specified:

```
<map key-type="java.util.TimeZone" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
```

In this case, spring probably determines it should invoked the property editors based on the mismatch between the provided values of type `String` and the requested types `TimeZone` and `Integer`.